# working around an error in a python module

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, module

So I have found an error in a module I am using (which one is unimportant, but if you must know it's [geopy.distance](https://code.google.com/p/geopy/source/browse/trunk/geopy/distance.py?r=105))

So I know what I have to do to fix the code, but when I open the .py file and edit it, it acts as if it was not edited!

Here is the error traceback before edited:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/geopy-0.95.1-py2.7.egg/geopy/distance.py", line 37, in __init__
    kilometers += self.measure(a, b)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/geopy-0.95.1-py2.7.egg/geopy/distance.py", line 72, in measure
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Here is the error traceback after I edit the file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/geopy-0.95.1-py2.7.egg/geopy/distance.py", line 37, in __init__
    kilometers += self.measure(a, b)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/geopy-0.95.1-py2.7.egg/geopy/distance.py", line 72, in measure
    a, b = Point(a), Point(b)
NotImplementedError
```

as you can see, I changed it so it would not `raise NotImplementedError`, but it is still raising it! How is this possible?

Comment: How did you change it? Shouldn't you be subclassing `Point` to override the `measure` method?

Comment: i'm not really sure what you mean? Point comes from `geopy.point`. Would you like me to add why measure is being weird in the code? I just deleted the `raise NotImplementedError` and replaced it with the distance measuring formula found in a later class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've edited a `.py` file, but the user process doesn't have permission to overwrite the `.pyc` file. The `NotImplementedError` is still on line 72 according to the `.pyc` file, but it's displaying the current line 72 from the `.py` file

Aside: Looks like `Distance` is an abstract class. You're not supposed to instantiate directly, but one of the subclasses of it. Eg `GreatCircleDistance` or `VincentyDistance`

Also notice the last two lines in the file

```
# Set the default distance formula to the most generally accurate.
distance = VincentyDistance
```

Comment: well that makes sense...but is it possible to edit a .pyc file?

Comment: wow, can't believe I missed that! Thank you, i'll mark as correct once I am allowed